# Wiring 2-way connected switch in 2-gang configuration

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've done this a few times now, but I've come across an odd wiring setup that I need a bit of guidance with. The current setup isn't using a netural, which I need for the connected switch, but instead has a single black wire that's stripped in one place to connect the two switches. (Bottom pole, leftmost switch.)

[image: Switch configuration]

My question is: based on this setup, what do I do with the single black wire, and what do I do with the maretted neturals? I'm guessing I have to split that wire into two segments, but I've never seen this sort of arrangement, so I'm a bit confused. Any info is very much appreciated.

[image: Clearer view of the box]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to install here? It's not clear if you're trying to put in a smart switch, or some other sort of thing altogether...

Comment: Yes, it's a smart switch. Leviton Z-wave.

Comment: Model # please?

Comment: It's a Leviton DZS15-1BZ Decora Z-Wave Controls 15-Amp Scene Capable Switch. I know how to install the switch normally though, my issue is more with the fact that there's no neutral to the existing switches, and there's no break in the jumper wire between the two switches, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The black coming in to the double loaded screw is the always hot. It is then jumpered over to the other switch. Each then has a switched how leaving to the lights.

you can make this proper by using another short black wire and wirenutting it along with the existing jumper wire and the always hot. Then every screw in the switch will have exactly 1 wire connecting it as is proper.

As for the neutral you can add a white wire to the wirenut to jump it over to the smart switch (though you may need to get a larger size nut).

Comment: So, I'd cut the black jumper wire so it was two segments instead of one continuous one with a bare section connected to the screw? In terms of the neutral, there are three in the wirenut at the back. Do I just take one from that to connect it to the switch, and if so, which one?

Comment: @RyanAnderson you have to add a wire to the neutral's wirenut to connect to the switch.